# CISCO IOSXE 16.9.2 radius key type 9 encryption?

Tags: cisco

I get a warning When I try to configure radius on a CISCO Switch 9300:
`Cisco IOSXE [Fuji], CAT9K_IOSXE), Version 16.9.2, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc4`)

Warning message once I add the Radius key:

**WARNING: Command has been added to the configuration using a type 0 password. However, type 0 passwords will soon be deprecated. Migrate to a supported password type**

I have the **service password-encryption** enabled globally which only does level 7 but cannot find any documentation if possible  to do Type 8 or 9 for radius key  configuration like I do for admin authentication for example:

```
enable algorithm-type scrypt secret password
username admin privilege 15 algorithm-type scrypt secret password
```

Warning occurs after I add:

```
radius server RADIUS-SERVER
address ipv4 IP auth-port 1812 acct-port 1813
timeout 2
retransmit 2
key password
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only encryption for the RAIDUS key is either Type0 (plain text) or 7 (encrypted).

I believe CISCO should remove this Warning message as it creates confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Cisco is doing this in another way:
You should replace your 
 `service password-encryption`
to
`password encryption aes`

This will change all the non encrypted passwords to type 6 (AES).
If you keep your type 7 for Radius -- it will not change for you! You need to enter them in clear text again!

I cannot see any head-to-head comparison between type 6 and type 9. I still *THINK* type 9 is better, I will keep type 9 on what they can provided (i.e. username and enable password)